# Handling Custom exception for rabbitmq listener connectivity issues

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I have a listener which consumes the messages from the third party producer.I need to send the custom error message in case of the queue connection issues

I'm new to rabbit mq .May I know what are the ways to handle the custom exception here

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `ConnectionListener` callback and inject it into a `org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory` configuration:

```
void addConnectionListener(ConnectionListener listener);
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#connection-channel-listeners